# cannot enable wifi in ubuntu 15.10 , device: dell inspiron 5520

Tags: networking, drivers

i tried lot of terminal codes such as

```
 1  lspci -nn | grep 0280
 2  sudo ifconfig wlan0 up
 3  sudo apt-get install git
 4  clear
 5  git clone https://github.com/lwfinger/rtlwifi_new.git
 6  cd rtlwifi_new
 7  make
 8  sudo make install
 9  sudo iwconfig
10  sudo lspci
11  clear
12  sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall
13  sudo iw reg get
14  iwconfig wlan0 power off
15  sudo iwconfig wlan0 power off
16  username -r
17  uname -r
18  sudo apt-get install linux-backports-cw-3.10-precise-generic-pae
19  sudo apt-get install linux-backports-cw-3.10-precise-generic
20  sudo modeprobe ath9k
21  sudo modprobe ath9k
22  sudo apt-get install linux-backports-cw-3.10-precise-generic-pae
23  sudo apt-get install linux-backports-cw-3.10-precise-generic
24  sudo modprobe ath9k
25  clear
26  gksudo gedit /etc/modules
27  sudo apt-get install gksu
28  clear
29  gksudo gedit /etc/modules
30  sudo modprobe -r b43
31  sudo modprobe -r ssb
32  sudo service network-manager stop
33  sudo gedit /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf
34  sudo rmmod iwlmvm iwlwifi
35  sudo modprobe iwlmvm iwlwifi
36  sudo service network-manager restart
37  sudo rmmod iwlwifi && sudo iwlwifi 11n_disable=1
38  iwconfig
39  iwconfig enp7s0 up
40  ifconfig enp7s0 up
41  sudo ifconfig enp7s0 up
42  sudo enps0 essid name key password
43  sudo iwconfig enps0 essid name key password
44  cd Desktop/
45  sudo dpkg -i *.deb
46  sudo -s gksu gedit /etc/modprobe.d/ath9k.conf
```

still i cannot solve my problem.

Comment: And what did the very first command return? Welcome to askubuntu.

Comment: 11, 25 and 28 are totally useless for your problem.

Comment: Please mark an awnser as accepted if your problem is solved!

Answer (score 0):

Try to type `rfkill list` if you see your device being soft blocked try to issue `sudo rfkill unblock <device id>` (or `sudo rfkill unblock all` to unblock everything).

Answer (score 0):

You will need to download & install the wifi driver (Broadcom) first. To do so, you require an internet connection, so you will have to use LAN.

After you have connected to the internet, enter this in the terminal:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install bmcwl-kernel-source
```

Now open "Additional Drivers" and select the driver that you installed. The wifi should work after that.